# One Time Login URL not Received : Looking for a Spare Solution

Tags: email, user-account

Drupal 7.56 / CiviCRM 4.7.20

Some (only a few) of my users do not receive the "one time login url" mail when they want to reset their (forgotten) password (also checked in spam and trash).

The odd thing is that if I personnaly send them a mail from postmaster@... (using thunderbird for instance), they receive it. 
They also receive it if I send it from CiviCRM (from any Organization or Individual).
I find no explanation to that.

So, I envisage to personnaly send them their [user:one-time-login-url]. Can I do that ? How ?

(I know that this is rather a Drupal specific question, and I submitted it to Drupal Stackexchange, but I also submit it here just in case someone has a solution : I thought I could include this [user:one-time-login-url] in a mail sent via CiviCRM, but this token is not available in Civi mailing feature).

Comment: This is a Drupal issue. Have you checked the Drupal logs to see if the mail is being sent?

Comment: Yes, the mail has been sent : I checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you have shell access and drush - then you can generate a one time user login link using

   drush uli USERNAME
2. Check the Site Name - make sure there are no non alphanumeric characters in it (they end up in the From and we’ve seen Postfix having issues parsing it). Update: specifically `:` in Site Name (as in admin/config/system/site-information - caused major issues;
3. Reputation: if email from your server arrives for some but not for others then that suggests a reputation issue - a server along the way has marked it as spam; use mxtoolbox.com to check if your domain is blacklisted somewhere.

Comment: Thank you Karin. 1. I don't have drush installed and don't know it : I have to investigate. 2. My site name has no special character (except "-" which is usually accepted). 3. I ran mxtoolbox and I found no blacklisting.

Comment: ad 2. I would definitively take that hyphen out;

Comment: Ah !!! That's a real problem : this site has existed for 2 years now, and has some hundreds of users : I can't change it any more.

Comment: Site name (not URL) as in: admin/config/system/site-information - I just check my logs/notes -> the non-alphanumeric char that what was causing failures was : in the site name; - is ok; will update answer

Comment: Thank you Karin ; that reassures me, ... but also leaves me only drush solution (have asked civihosting to install drush : waiting for their answer) ; but any other spare solution is welcome. I have tried to develop a smal php which calls user_pass_reset_url($account) function, but I get a"'DrupalDefaultEntityController' class not found" error that I can't solve.

Comment: I finally could use your suggestion 1 (drush uli USERNAME), ... and it worked. Thank you Karin.

Comment: awesome - welcome to drush